# Why am I getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘isEE’)" when accessing Strapi admin panel via nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, nginx, content-management-system, strapi

Recently I’ve deployed my strapi app using Nginx and when I’m trying to access admin page I’m getting this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia7nf.png)

I have no idea what does this error means:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isEE')
    at main.0dc07489.js:8914:25883
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at it (main.0dc07489.js:8914:25430)
```

When I’m accessing Strapi app directly by IP and port 1337 everything works fine. I’ve tried many things like deploying the new Strapi app but I can’t figure out what’s wrong.

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you look for occurrences of `isEE` in your code and check how the object on which it is accessed could be `undefined`?

Answer (score 2):

We faced a similar issue when we started using the custom PUBLIC_URL parameter and got rid of it when it was returned to an empty string value. I'm not sure it is the same case but just letting you all know about this nuance.
Versions - Strapi: 4.5.3, npm: 8.19.2, node: 16.18.1